Worksheet_Change Workaround for automatic cell changes
I'm relatively new to VBA and I am struggling with a worksheet_change problem. I am trying to make the attached code work to automatically change cells A47:B53 when any of the "YES"/"no" cells change. The problem is that the "Yes"/"no" changes are automatic based on a formula. I know that Worksheet_change doesn't work for cells that change based on a formula and it is primarily for manual changes (like dropdowns or something), but how can I change the code to do what I need it to do? Is there a way to use Worksheet_Calculate or something?
When a cell is "Yes" I want the associated cell in the blue area to change to "Enter %" and when a cell is "no" I want the associated cell in the blue area to change to "0". I want to then be able to change the "Enter %" to any number I want and it will stay the same until the "Yes" turns into a "no" and makes it 0 again. I hope this makes sense. See the name manager to see the cell names.
I've tried worksheet_change options but through researching solutions I found that this only works for manual changes. The problem is that I want to be able to type over the "Enter %" and only have that change again when the "Yes" becomes a "no" again.
Here is the formula in the YES/no cells (the YES/no cells are what are called "Brad#a" or "Nick#a", whereas the "Brad#b" or "Nick#b" are where I want the output from the code to be located)
=IF(SUM(A$34:A$36)=0,"no","YES")
Here is the code in VBA I have:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)

'Brad
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad7a")) Is Nothing Then

      If Range("Brad7a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad7b") = "Enter %"
      ElseIf Range("Brad7a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad7b") = "0"
      End If
      
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad6a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Brad6a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad6b") = "Enter %"
      ElseIf Range("Brad6a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad6b") = "0"
      End If
    
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad5a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Brad5a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad5b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Brad5a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad5b") = "0"
      End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad4a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Brad4a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad4b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Brad4a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad4b") = "0"
      End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad3a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Brad3a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad3b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Brad3a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad3b") = "0"
      End If
    
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad2a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Brad2a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad2b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Brad2a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad2b") = "0"
      End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Brad1a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Brad1a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad1b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Brad1a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Brad1b") = "0"
      End If


'Nick
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick7a")) Is Nothing Then

      If Range("Nick7a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick7b") = "Enter %"
      ElseIf Range("Nick7a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick7b") = "0"
      End If
      
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick6a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Nick6a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick6b") = "Enter %"
      ElseIf Range("Nick6a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick6b") = "0"
      End If
    
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick5a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Nick5a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick5b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Nick5a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick5b") = "0"
      End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick4a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Nick4a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick4b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Nick4a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick4b") = "0"
      End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick3a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Nick3a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick3b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Nick3a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick3b") = "0"
      End If
    
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick2a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Nick2a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick2b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Nick2a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick2b") = "0"
      End If

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Destination, Range("Nick1a")) Is Nothing Then
  
      If Range("Nick1a") = "YES" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick1b") = "Enter %"
       ElseIf Range("Nick1a") = "no" Then
         Sheets("Resource Allocation").Range("Nick1b") = "0"
      End If
    
   End If

End Sub



If (eg) A$34:A$36 are manually-changed then you can trap the Change event in those cells; otherwise you can use the Calculate event as in my answer below.

Something like this maybe, using the Calculate event:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    CheckYesNo Me 'in the sheet code module, Me = the worksheet
End Sub


Sub CheckYesNo(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim arrNames, i As Long, el, nm As String, v, c As Range
    
    arrNames = Array("Brad", "Nick")
    
    For Each el In arrNames            'loop names
        For i = 7 To 1 Step -1
            nm = el & i                'eg "Brad7", "Nick3"
            Set c = ws.Range(nm & "b") 'updating this cell
            Select Case Me.Range(nm & "a").Value
                Case "YES"
                    'don't replace any already-entered numbers....
                    If Len(c.Value) = 0 Or Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                        c.Value = "Enter %"
                    End If
                Case "no"
                    c.Value = 0
            End Select
        Next i
    Next el
End Sub

